# Grouping a base64->buffer hex string by bytes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, base64, hex, buffer

I'm trying to take a Base64 string, convert it to a hex string and group the output by bytes.

I'd like the output of console.log(bufferString) to be:

`03 67 00 cf 04 68 61 00 ff 01 2d`

But I'm stuck with this output:

`036700cf04686100ff012d`

What I've got so far...

```
let request = {
    "PayloadData": "A2cAzwRoYQD/AS0=",
    "FPort": 10
  }

let buffer = Buffer.from(request.PayloadData, 'base64');
let bufferString = buffer.toString('hex');

console.log(bufferString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `atob()` and then splitting each character into an array, map each element of the array to a hex value and then join it back together with a space.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob

See snippet below.

```js
const output = {}
const fx = {
  encodeB64String: string => btoa(string),
  decodeB64String: b64String => atob(b64String),
  b64ToBytes: b64String => fx.decodeB64String(b64String)
    .split(``)
    .map(el => el.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, `0`))
    .join(` `),
  bytesToB64: bytes => fx.encodeB64String(bytes
    .split(` `)
    .map(el => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(el, 16)))
    .join(``))
}

let request = {
  "PayloadData": "A2cAzwRoYQD/AS0=",
  "FPort": 10
}
console.log({
  opExample: fx.b64ToBytes(request.PayloadData)
});

output.inputString = `Hello World!`;
output.b64String = fx.encodeB64String(output.inputString);
output.b64ToBytes = fx.b64ToBytes(output.b64String);
output.bytesToB64 = fx.bytesToB64(output.b64ToBytes);
output.decodedString = fx.decodeB64String(output.bytesToB64);
console.log(output);
```